# Keras: very low accuracy, very high loss and predictions are the same for every input

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras

I am developing a system for general-purpose audio tagging using keras.

I have the following data input:

x_train has 10 different data for each input (data length, max, min, etc.) y_train represents 41 possible labels (guitar, bass, etc.)

Here is my code below:

```
x_train shape = (7104, 10)
y_train shape = (41,)

print(x_train[0])

[ 3.75732000e+05 -2.23437546e-05 -1.17187500e-02  1.30615234e-02
  2.65964586e-03  2.65973969e-03  9.80024859e-02  1.13624850e+00
  1.00003528e+00 -1.11458333e+00] 

print(y_train[0])

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

My model is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu', input_dim=10))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(41, activation='softmax'))

opt = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), epochs=5, batch_size=8)
```

This is my result:

```
Epoch 1/5
7104/7104 [==============================] - 1s 179us/step - loss: 15.7392 - acc: 0.0235
Epoch 2/5
7104/7104 [==============================] - 1s 132us/step - loss: 15.7369 - acc: 0.0236
Epoch 3/5
7104/7104 [==============================] - 1s 133us/step - loss: 15.7415 - acc: 0.0234
Epoch 4/5
7104/7104 [==============================] - 1s 132us/step - loss: 15.7262 - acc: 0.0242
Epoch 5/5
7104/7104 [==============================] - 1s 132us/step - loss: 15.6484 - acc: 0.0291
```

As you can see, my results show very high data loss and very low accuracy. The main problem occurs when I try to predict the result. For each one input the output is the same. How can I fix this?

````
pre = model.predict(np.array(x_train), batch_size=8, verbose=0)

for i in pre:
    print(i)

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
...

```
````

Comment: Your model is not learning. There could be many reasons for that. Everything from "not enough labeled data" to "the relationship is unlearnable".